# Pine Code version 5 question about strategy entry

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api, crossover, horizontal-line

i have applied this LINE code to my strategy script and i draws the line exactly how i wanted, the problem is when I try to use the my_buyLine for an entry confluence, I get an error.

Can you help me understand why and how to fix this problem?

I have attempted to figure it out by researching more information about LINES but I haven't had any success, please forgive my ignorance, I am a beginner pine coder.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hpw5y.png)

I have tried researching information about LINES and also tried looking at other peoples scripts to see if they have a similar coding but i have not had any success.

Comment: Why should images of code/data/errors should not be uploaded https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors